# Trying to get test email working in cakephp

Tags: php, email, cakephp

I'm trying to use the "Sending a basic message" code from here to send an email:
http://book.cakephp.org/view/1283/Email#!/view/1286/Sending-a-basic-message

The code appears to work but I never receive the email (I've verified that the email address is valid). I haven't configured an email server anywhere in PHP, but the instructions make no mention of that. Here's the output when I set

```
 $this->Email->delivery = 'debug';
```

.

```
To: Somebody Else 
From: Somebody 
Subject: Test
Header:

From: Somebody  
Message-ID: <4daa65cd-beb8-4bf6-8cec-1dc07b5e5e4c@localhost>
Date: Sat, 16 Apr 2011 22:00:13 -0600
X-Mailer: CakePHP Email Component
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bitParameters:

Message:

Hello message body!
```

Comment: What platform at you on? On Windows you'd need to be running a local SMTP server, or at least specify one in the php configuration. If you're on a Unix/Linux server, you might have one already, so check the /var/log/maillog and see what's happening to the mail - it could be getting trashed as spam.

Comment: I'm on centOS 5.5. My machine is not set up for sending emails so I would have to route through something like google SMTP.

Comment: Ok. Edit0 added. Another point which crossed my mind while reading through the other posts is, that (afaik) CakePHP can speak directly with SMTP through socket connections. So I would try to make sure that the settings (as in my edit0) are correct, than go on log-file hunt (CakePHP logs in app/tmp/logs) Ü

Answer (score 1, accepted):

opike,

if you use the `debug` setting, then you are *not* sending an email, but rather displaying it.
See [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1283/Email#!/view/1284/Class-Attributes-and-Variables).

For a proper setup, see [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1283/Email#!/view/1290/Sending-A-Message-Using-SMTP). So you do not need a MTA like *exim* or *sendmail* configured, but rather use your ISP (aka (here), your normal email address) to do the work.

**Edit0:**
And you definitly set it up like the book dictates?:

```
   /* SMTP Options, !with the settings of your ISP substituted in! */
   $this->Email->smtpOptions = array(
        'port'=>'465', 
        'timeout'=>'30',
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'username'=>'your_username@gmail.com',
        'password'=>'your_gmail_password',
   );
```

Comment: Right, I'm aware of the behavior of the debug setting. I just did that for additional information for this thread. When I do the actual test, I turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the phpinfo() function in a file of its own and look to see if you're PHP installation is using something like sendmail. Most likely, you don't have an SMTP server installed or it's not properly configured in your php.ini file.

Is there anything (error) in the PHP logs?

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

Comment: Here are the smtp properties in phpinfo(): SMTP localhost localhost smtp_port 25 25 My server is not set up to send emails so I need to use something like google SMTP.